# Misplacement of contents of UIView

Tags: iphone, subview

I have a `UIView` and `UIButton` (declared in `viewDidLoad:` method of RootViewcontroller. ).

```
UIView  *geopointView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 320, 120, 100)] ;
UIButton *mybutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 330, 120, 30)] ;
```

mybutton is added to geopointView.

```
  [geopointView addsubView:mybutton];
```

Finally UIView is added to RootViewController in method showTheView (defined in rootViewController)

```
-(void) showTheView{
    [self.view addsubView:geopointView];
}
```

but when this method is called,I find that both mybutton and geopointView are visible but  mybutton is not placed inside of geopointView.  mybutton's bounds now appear as `CGRectmake(10, 250, 120, 30);`

Can anyone please tell what I am missing here. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: post ur sceenshot and let me know

Comment: Your geoView itself is 100 pixels tall, but you put the button's to 330.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  UIbutton *mybutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 30)] ;
```

Comment: for instant help  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/conversation/do-u-want-instant-help-for-ur-question-or-r-u-new-bee-to-iphone-ipad-develop

Answer (score 0):

The frame of your button should be relative to the parent's *bounds*, but it appears to be relative to the screen.  If you want your button to be inside the geopointView it needs to have x, y coordinates that fit within the width (120) and height (100) of geopointView, so something like this will put it in the top left corner (0,0) of geopointView:

```
UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,120,30)];
```

Comment: Thank you progrmr for your explanation.